Issue in numerical integration of $\frac{1}{4\pi^{3/2}i}\int_Ce^{-\frac{z^3}{12}-tz}z^{-1/2}dz$
I am trying to numerically integrate the integral representation of $\operatorname{Ai}^2(x)$. The representation is
$$\operatorname{Ai}^2(t)=\frac{1}{4\pi^{3/2}i}\int_Ce^{-\frac{z^3}{12}-tz}z^{-1/2}dz.$$
Where the contour $C$ has upper portion $y_1(x)=\sqrt{3}\sqrt{x^2-4}$ and lower portion $y_2(x)=-\sqrt{3}\sqrt{x^2-4}$ where $x\in[2,\infty)$.

Since most of the integral is concentrated near the origin as, I can take the domain $x\in[2,10]$. Then I chop up the domain into $n$ bins.
$$\operatorname{Ai}^2(t)=\frac{1}{4\pi^{3/2}i}\int_Ce^{-\frac{z^3}{12}-tz}z^{-1/2}dz\approx\sum_{i=0}^n f((2+i\Delta x,y_i(2+i\Delta x)), t)\Delta y$$
where $f(z,t)=\frac{1}{4\pi^{3/2}i}e^{-\frac{z^3}{12}-tz}z^{-1/2}$. However, when I do this, the answer does not agree with the correct solution. Where have I gone wrong?
import math
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import special
import numpy as np

def y1(x):
  return np.sqrt(3)*np.sqrt(x**2-4)

def y2(x):
  return -np.sqrt(3)*np.sqrt(x**2-4)

def f(z,t):
  return 1/(4*math.pi**(3/2)*(1j))*np.exp((z**3)/12-t*z)*(z**(-1/2))

def integral(t):
  bins= 1000  

  # Upper contour
  x=np.linspace(2,10,bins)
  output = 0
  for i in range(1, len(x)):
    dy = (y1(x[i])-y1(x[i-1]))
    output += f(complex(x[i],y1(x[i])),t)*dy

  # Lower contour
  for i in range(1, len(x))[::-1]:
    dy = (y2(x[i])-y2(x[i-1]))
    output += f(complex(x[i],y2(x[i])),t)*dy

  return output

t=np.linspace(-4,4,100)

# Numerical Answer 
plt.plot(t, [integral(index) for index in t])
# Actual answer
plt.plot(t, [special.airy(index)[0]**2 for index in t])

plt.ylim(-1, 2)

Here is a publicly editable co-lab notebook with the running code
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1PuibieIHpKKSbscHwZB0Gv9It9HcpfpF?usp=sharing


$$\operatorname{Ai}^2(t)=\frac{1}{{4 \pi ^{3/2} i}}{\int_{\sigma-i \infty }^{\sigma+i \infty } e^ \left(\color{red}+\frac{z^3}{12}-t z\right)\cdot z^{-\frac{1}{2}}  \, dz}$$
Use SciPy Gaussian quadrature:
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import special
import scipy.integrate as integrate

sigma = 1/10

# Integrand
def f(z,t):
    return np.exp(+1/12*z**3-t*z)*z**(-1/2)

# Numerical approximation of AiryAi(t)**2
def integral(t):
    output = integrate.quadrature(lambda w: f(sigma+1j*w,t), 0, 20, tol=1e-9, maxiter=500)
    return np.real(1/(2*np.pi**(3/2)) * output[0])

# Numerical approximation of AiryAi(t)
def airyAi(t):
    output = integrate.quadrature(lambda z: np.cos(1/3*z**3 + t*z), 0, 12, tol=1e-9, maxiter=500)
    return 1/np.pi * output[0]

t = np.linspace(-10,10,1001)

# Numerical Answer
plt.plot(t, [integral(index) for index in t])

# Actual answer
plt.plot(t, [special.airy(index)[0]**2 for index in t])

